# Open file in VBA on Mac

Tags: excel, vba

Beginner!
Having a problem creating a file on Mac using VBA.
I copied the folders pathname but it does not work. Error says - "bad file name or number". I suspect that the problem lies within the pathname, if so what is the right way?

```
Public Sub task()
Open "/Users/user/test.csv" For Output As file
Close file
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this for the docs on Open:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/open-statement

In your case:

```
Public Sub task()
Open "/Users/user/test.csv" For Output As #1
' do whatever output you need here, then ...
Close #1
End Sub
```

Because of Apple's sandboxing, there might be other issues with the file path, but try the above for starters.

Comment: This worked! For some reason thought that "#1" naming is not mandatory.

Comment: @KristapsĀlmanis - one can use [`FreeFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/freefile-function) to get the next available file number too, instead of hard-coding a file number.

Comment: @BigBen Yes, and it's generally best practice to do so.
Dim iFile As Integer
iFile = FreeFile()
Then
Open "fullfilepath" For Output as #iFile